# Exclude a particular type from `any`

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function that currently takes an input of type `any` and logs it:

```
function foo(input: any): void { // log input }
```

My project has a particular type that is used for secrets, and I'd like to make sure that `foo` is never called with an argument of type `Secret` (but all other types are still ok).

I tried the following:

```
function foo(input: Exclude<any, Secret>): void { // log input }
```

but this passes the typecheck even when I call `foo` on an input of type `Secret` (here's a [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUMwAcRQFyICiAHhADYgAmApgDwCGYAngDSIDOUATpgOYB8ASgIA3ODEqIA3gChE8xBATs4ZagDoycXhmy5BAbhkBfGTKVhOiegU48wvRAF5EAIgAW1MltdGU6ekMgA) that shows the problem where I'm using `string` instead of `secret`).

How can I construct the complement type of `Secret`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic, and check if it extends `Secret`. If it does, then make the parameter type `never` so typescript errors:

```
function foo<T>(input: T extends Secret ? never : T): void {
    console.log(input);
}
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVAfAChmABxCgC5ENEBTADykrABMBnRJqAJ3wHNEB+RMJQBuldojIYAlGSFwYDRAG8AUIjWIICJnAA2lAHQ64XPIWKSA3MoC+y5ZrBtEAQzJtOYHgF5EAIgAWlDpGvlYocDjOlkA).

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that I'll also need to guarantee that none of the values are records whose keys might be `Secret`s. I've played around with defining a recursive `ContainsSecret` type, but it doesn't seem to be working as I expected.

```
type ContainsString<T> = T extends string ? T : (T extends {[k: string]: ContainsString<T>} ? T : never);

const a: ContainsString<number> = 2; // this (unexpectedly) typechecks
```

What am I missing?